# How to solve following Optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The following is the mathematical expression for my model's rate expression. Variable $x1,x2$ are the controlling parameter, while the rest are positive constants.

$$\max_{x1,x2} \ x_1\tau_k K\sum_{j=1}^{J}\frac{(-1)^{(j+1)}}{a (j+1)b^{^2}} - \tau_k K + \epsilon c^3x_2^3\ \ (s.t. \ 0<\ x_1 <\ 1,\ 0<\  x_2<\ 1)$$

Can I mathematically say that it is a convex problem within the limits of variables $x1,x2$? The graph for $x^3 \ \forall\  x>0$ strictly follows the definition of convexity.

[image: Graph of problem above]

Furthermore, which mathematical tool can I use to solve this problem? (I will be using Matlab for execution).

Comment: If $a,b$ are constants, the infinite sum's terms don't go to zero and the function is ill-defined!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks and my apologies. The actual expression contains $(j+1)$ in the denominator as well. Also, j starts from '1' and not '0' as in the previous expression. I suppose I can fix the upper limit of Summation to a very large value such as J, now shown in the edited version because as J increase, $\frac{1}{j+1}$ diminishes to Zero. Does it make sense? I think, doing so will add another variable $j$. Isn't it right?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}n = \ln 2$, which makes your expression $$x_1\tau_kK\frac{1-\ln 2}{ab^2}-\tau_kK + \epsilon c^3x_2^3$$ (setting $J = \infty$ again - it was enough to add the $j+1$ in the denominator to make it convergent - though just barely). Or collecting all the constant multipliers in to single coefficients, $$Ax_1 + Bx_2^3 + C$$It is not too hard to show from the definition that this is convex.